# activity did not call through super.onresume exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-lifecycle

In my xamarin forms app, there is crash which is as follows from App Center crashlytics:

**android.app.Activity.performResume**:

```
Activity.java - line 7138
android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity 
{com.tcrsoftware.androidx/md54f7a5b50cfc6839da41f22f8e0e378f9.MainActivity} 
did not call through to super.onResume()
android.app.Activity.performResume Activity.java:7138
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity ActivityThread.java:3850
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity ActivityThread.java:3914
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage ActivityThread.java:1709
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:102
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:154
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:6823
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
ZygoteInit.java:1557
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:1445
```

I just use `onResume()` in my Shared Library project like:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
protected override void OnResume()
    {
        Utility.LogMessage("OnResume: ", LogMessageType.info);
    }
}
```

I did not implement/use `onResume()` in the `MainActivity` class of android project.

Where and why this crash occured? And also would it be cause app to crash continously when user tries to open the app?

any updates?

Comment: I saw they have one open ticket on this case : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56948

Comment: ya but there is no solution posted. Also this issue is random. I do not know how t o reproduce.

Comment: interesting part is even i dont have onResume() method in MainActivity.cs class i got this crash from one of the user